# Is there a faster way to generate this pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two dataframes `s` and `sk` with around `1M` elements and I need to generate a new dataframe `df` from it where:

```
df.iloc[i] = s.iloc[f(i)] / sk.iloc[g(i)]
```

where `f` and `g` are functions that return integers.

Currently I'm doing:

```
data = []
for i in range(s.shape[0])):
    data.append(s.iloc[f(i)] / sk.iloc[g(i)])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=s.columns)
```

But this seems slow. It's taking about 5 minutes (the dataframes have 9 `float` columns).

There are only`10M` divisions, so 5 minutes seems sub-par. All the time seems to be spent iterating `s` and `sk`, so I was wondering if there was a way to build `s[f]` and `sk[g]` quickly?

**edit**

`f` and `g` are simple functions similar to

```
def f(i): return math.ceil(i / 23)
def g(i): return math.ceil(i / 23) + ((i - 1) % 23)
```

Comment: What does f(i) returns?

Comment: what are `f` and `g`?

Comment: Try make f and g vectorized and your problem can be easily solved

Comment: see above, i've updated the question

Comment: What makes you think there will only be 10m output rows?  Index alignment is going to mess up your output here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functions are easily vectorized.

---

```
def f_vec(i):
    return np.ceil(i / 23).astype(int)

def g_vec(i):
    return (np.ceil(i / 23) + ((i - 1) % 23)).astype(int)
```

As @Wen points out, we can further optimize this by writing a wrapper to only calculate the ceiling once.

```
def wrapper(i, a, b):
    cache_ceil = np.ceil(i / 23).astype(int)
    fidx = cache_ceil
    gidx = cache_ceil + ((i - 1) % 23)
    return a.iloc[fidx].to_numpy() / b.iloc[gidx].to_numpy()
```

---

Index alignment is also not working in your favor here.  If you truly want the elementwise division of the two results, drop down to `numpy` before dividing:

```
s.iloc[f_vec(idx)].to_numpy() / sk.iloc[g_vec(idx)].to_numpy()
```

---

Now to test out the speed.

***Setup***

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (1_000_000, 10))
s = pd.DataFrame(a)
sk = pd.DataFrame(a)
idx = np.arange(1_000_000)
```

***Performance***

```
%timeit s.iloc[f_vec(idx)].to_numpy() / sk.iloc[g_vec(idx)].to_numpy()
265 ms ± 5.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit wrapper(idx, s, sk)
200 ms ± 3.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: One small enhance , since f and g share the same part `np.ceil(i / 23).astype(int)` , can we call it once? just for f

Comment: Perfect! You've taken 5 minutes down to about 5 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: @WeNYoBen good point, updated the answer to add a wrapper to only calculate that once.

Comment: @user3483203 nice one :-)